# Windows 7 Taskbar disappears

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

I am using my Lenovo b550 Windows 7 laptop with a projector for training. For the last few days, I have noticed that my taskbar does not remain on top of other applications.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally after lots of day spend with the problem i found solution.

i just accidently press F11 yes F11 key (shortcut key to toggle fullscreen mode in chrome) and my problem is solved.

i thinks this is some sort of bug in chrome or other software installed in my machine but finally it is solved.

Answer (score 0):

If the projector is in extended desktop mode, it will not have the taskbar.

If the projector is cloned desktop mode or the only desktop, it will autohide the taskbar if the taskbar property is set to auto hide.

You can verify this by right-clicking the taskbar and selecting proprties... second from the top under the Taskbar tab is "auto hide"